# How to start an Activity task using Threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent, android-handler

I want to start the **Main2Activity's** task(Loading the WebView) when button is pressed but not to show the Main2Activity's Screen until **onPageFinished()** is called. i had some ideas to get this by Intents however it seems doesn't work.
Here my code :

**MainActivity.java** :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }

            };
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
    );
 }

 }
```

**Main2Activity.java** :

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

Intent intent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    final WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
            intent.putExtra("DONE",1);

            //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done!", 
            //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
    });
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.2.html");
}
}
```

is this possible using Intents or i have to do this with some other techniques?
How can i Achieve this goal ?

Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should directly go to Main2Activity on button click, without calling any thread in MainActivity.

Then in Main2Activity show an image or something until onPageFinished() is called.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback , but i want to stay in MainActivity until the onPageFinished() in Main2Activity is called.